# CTE query not returning request in Oracle over ODBC or OLE but does in PLSQL

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I have a fairly complex CTE query (with statements) that runs just fine in Oracle 11g on PL/SQL Developer but returns a null set (no error, just null recordset) via both OLE and ODBC using all flavors of drivers for Oracle in .NET 4.5 C#.

I have tried prefacing the query with a ";" to try and terminate any kind of hanging open statement before my code but this just throws an exception.  I have tried 'unrolling' the CTE and doing all subqueries and the performance goes to the dogs (which is interesting, surprised the optimizer sucks that much).

At this point I just don't know what to do.  This rather complex query is the only way I can get the data out of the database that I need, but I'm stuck on how to get results back into code.  Thoughts?  (I hesitate to post the query because it is extremely long and likely wouldn't make a lot of sense.)

Here is my data access methods for c# ODBC and OLE:

```
class ODBCConn
{
    public OdbcConnection conn;
    public OdbcDataReader reader;
    public OdbcCommand cmd;
    string connStr = "";
    public ODBCConn(){
        try{
            connStr = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=MyServer;Uid=analytics;Pwd=Somepassword;";
            conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr);
            conn.ConnectionTimeout = 300;
            conn.Open();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public OdbcDataReader ReadData(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return reader;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
class Conn
{
    public OleDbConnection conn;
    public OleDbDataReader reader;
    public OleDbCommand cmd;
    string connStr = "";
    public Conn()
    {
        try
        {
            //connStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyServer;User Id=analytics;Password=Somepassword;";
            connStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyServer;User Id=analytics;Password=Somepassword;";
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);                
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public OleDbDataReader ReadData(string sql){
        try{
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message );
        }
        return reader;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use SQL trace with level 12 to compare statement execution via sql developer and odbc.

Comment: I used the Oracle.DataAccess components in C# to run the exact same query.  Results were the same as PL/SQL.  It would seem that the OLE and ODBC drivers have some problem with complex CTE statements?

Comment: Is it an option to create a view in the database?

Comment: What Oracle driver are you using?  ODP.net?  Also, can you post your C#?

Comment: Not an option to create a view in the database, otherwise I would have done that for sure.  Good thought, DCookie.

Comment: Added C# data access methods for OLE and ODBC.  These methods work for simple queries no problem, but fail on Oracle (and *only* Oracle) for CTE queries.  They work just fine on SQL Server.